# Passing data which is stored in firebase from one activity to another

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my codes in one activity that kept my database values in a textview:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_how_much);

    myAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    myDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    hay=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hay);

    String user_id = myAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference userid_database = myDatabase.child(user_id);
    DatabaseReference book1 = userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 1").child("Page");
    book1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            hay.setText(text);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });




}
public void transfer(View view){
    String value = hay.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(HowMuch.this, Basit.class);
    intent.putExtra("key",value);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is my other activity codes:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basit);

    textbasit=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textbasit);
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    String value = bundle.getString("key");
    textbasit.setText(value);

}
```

This is my error:

in this line: String value = bundle.getString("key");
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

In my first activity value seems in "hay" textview. I want to get that value in another activity without using more textview to kept it by onDataChange method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a check on getIntent().getExtras() to see if it returning null
and also don't need to use bundle.
e.g.`

```
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("key") != null) {
    String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
    textbasit.setText(value);
}
```

`

Comment: I didn't understand get.getString part.

Comment: @BüsraNurAkgül it was a typo i have edited the answer

Comment: @BüsraNurAkgül does textView hay display your text

Comment: Yes. It displays.

Comment: Yes. There is no error and no output. Just an empty screen.

Comment: @BüsraNurAkgül  does second activity launches or not

Comment: It lunches but there is no value in "textbasit" TextView.

Comment: @BüsraNurAkgül that's weird  i don't see a problem in your code

Comment: Me too. Do you have any advice to me? I want to use the values which are stored in firebase database for making calculations with them.

Comment: @BüsraNurAkgül declare text string in class level and use that for putting value in intent and also use log statement to see if values are working as supposed

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you other activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtra("key")){
        textbasit.setText(intent.getStringExtra("key"));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I wrote it, there is no error and also there is no output.

Comment: Then you must check that are you're not passing an empty string in extras

Comment: In my first activity, there is a value in "hay" textview that I can see on the screen.

Comment: Okay i found the issue

Comment: You're using intent.putExtra() you should use intent.putStringExtra() instead of this.. Try this hope this would resolve your issue

Comment: It said cannot resolve 'putStringExtra(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'.

Comment: Yes i got it.. There is no such method putStringExtra()

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this,"value:"+value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();´  check if you're passing a null string in extras